# How do I select an area with an exact width and height from the center of an image in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, cropping

I want to select part of a photo I'm editing in Photoshop. The source is 1920 wide and I want to select 720 from the middle so discarding 600 pixels from left and right. Is this possible in Photoshop?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about software product and not photography.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Given that Photoshop has it's own [tag](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tags/photoshop), I'd suggest that questions on using Photoshop *are* on topic

Comment: @PeterM, check again the question and tell me where is the photography involved.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Where it literally says *"I want to select part of a **photo** I'm editing"*

Comment: To clarify the Photoshop status: questions about Photoshop are on-topic only if they relate to photography; "how do I use Photoshop remove a distracting object from <example photo>" is definitely on-topic, "how do I draw a dinosaur in Photoshop?" is definitely off-topic. Other cases are somewhere in the middle. I'll improve the tag to include this information.

Answer (score 2):

Choose "fixed size" in the Marquee selection tool ribbon and set it to 720x720 (or 720xH for whatever your height is). Then place a selection on the canvas. Then drag it left or right until it centers (the center vertical line should show when it does).

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the rulers.  In my version there is a selection under the View menu.
Make sure guides are visible under View->Show
Drag from the vertical ruler on to the picture to create a guide.  As you move it you can see the pixel position.  Position guides at the points you want to select.  You may have to zoom in a lot to get the exact pixel position.
The rectangular selection tool will snap to the guides.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential way to do this is by changing the canvas size.  (I don't have Photoshop, but I believe that this will work - it works in Affinity Photo :D)

1. Select *Image*=>*Canvas Size* (which opens the Canvas size dialog box)
2. In the "*New Size*" section, set the anchor to be the center box
3. Leave the "*Height*" as is
4. Set the "*Width*" to be 720 pixels
5. Leave "*Relative*" unchecked.
6. Click on "*Ok*"

This should take the 720 pixels around the center of the image and effectively crop out the left and right 600 pixels.

---

Down voter care to explain?
Does this method *not* work?

Comment: Resizing the canvas is different than making a marquee selection.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson Fair comment, but the OPs question can be read in terms of cropping with the use of "discard" verbiage

Comment: Perhaps. Definitely something to clarify, as "select" is a specific term in PS. (I'll also note that in PS, "cropping" is different than resizing the canvas, as well.)